# suppress version information when running matlab scripts from the command line

Tags: matlab

When running a matlab script from the command line (e.g., `matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "some_m_file; quit;"`), something akin to the following is inevitably sent to `stdout`:

```
$ matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -r "fprintf('hello world\n'); quit;"

                            < M A T L A B (R) >
                  Copyright 1984-2016 The MathWorks, Inc.
                   R2016b (9.1.0.441655) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                             September 7, 2016


For online documentation, see http://www.mathworks.com/support
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.

hello world
```

Can this text be suppressed? One could remove it by piping the script output through `tail -n+11` (assuming the number of lines is stable across versions) but I am wondering whether there is a command line option to Matlab that will prevent it from being printed in the first place.